# How to select distinct rows with respect to only certain columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I'm using the *select* below.

```
select 
  A.Bada, 
  B.Boom, 
  ' ' as '---', * ...
```

There's a bunch of joins along the way and now I have all the data I need **but** certain rows are repeated with respect to *Bada* and *Boom*. Those are not really **exact duplicates** because some values brought in by the star differ. However, those are not relevant to my case.

The solution I'm applying now is simply listing the interesting columns explicitly but I wonder of there's a smooth way to eliminate the rows that have *Bada* and *Boom* repeated (keeping only one occurrence of such row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window and ranking functions.  As such, you can choose a particular or arbitrary rows in a set a rows with the same values in some columns:

```
select t.* from (
  select 
    t.bada,
    t.boom, 
    row_number() over (partition by bada, boom order by bada) as seqnum,
    t.*,
    from table t) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This works by first adding a sequence number of each row *over* a *partition* of the original table. Something like row number by only consecutive with respect to selected columns. Once that's done, it's possible to pick a certain value of the consecutive counter, e.g. 1.

```
select 
  t.bada,
  t.boom, 
  row_number() over (partition by bada, boom order by bada) as seqnum,
  t.*,
from table t
```

If you want a particular row -- such as the most recent one -- then adjust the `order by` to get that row.

Comment: Now, it's **perfect**. At least in my eyes. Clearly accepted answer!